# SQL Server 2012 table lock on update command

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have a table which contains above 2 millions records. When 50 users tries to update the same table SQL 1205 lock occurs and users have to wait for more then 20 seconds for update query which execute in milliseconds.

It is a simple one table update query.

I am using SQL Server 2012 and Asp.net MVC for server side

Comment: SO what you want to do ? Decrease the waiting time or you want it removed?

Comment: Yes i want to decrease the waiting time and remove the locks